# Qt embeded windows have black edge?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to write a Qt applicat to embeded [scrcpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1v4j.png) window.
[Scrcpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1v4j.png) is a app that mirror android emulator or ture smartphone.
I had successful embed it, but the window not work fine with black edge.

**The code:**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QWindow
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest
import win32gui

class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_process()
        self.initUI()

    def start_process(self):
        path = r"C:\Users\jekoie\Downloads\Compressed\tools"
        self.ps = QProcess()
        self.ps.setWorkingDirectory(path)
        self.ps.setProgram(path+"\scrcpy-noconsole.exe")
        self.ps.setInputChannelMode(QProcess.ForwardedInputChannel)
        self.ps.start()
        self.ps.waitForStarted()

    def initUI(self):
        hwid = 0
        while hwid == 0:
            QTest.qWait(1000)
            hwid = win32gui.FindWindow("SDL_app", None)

        win = QWindow.fromWinId(hwid)
        widget = self.createWindowContainer(win)
        widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

app = QApplication([])
demo = Demo()
demo.resize(400, 700)
demo.show()
app.exec()
```

**adb connect android emulator:**
[image]

**Look like:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question, what do you want to get? Could you show a picture of what you want to get

Comment: @eyllanesc i had update my post.